# How to add sum of currency values of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, protractor

how to add currency values of an array like this

```js
array = [ '$0',
  '$0',
  '$14,792',
  '$152,445',
  '$1,581,033',
  '$2,988,978',
  '$4,226,419',
  '$7,254,960',
  '$10,726,945',
  '$12,657,402',
  '$35,215,787',
  '$37,968,368',
  '$7,648,445',
  '$364,237',
  '$390,395',
  '$306,080',
  '$3,641,253',
  '$4,328,363',
  '$1,360,664' ]
```

here is my method defined, the only problem i am facing is in the second for array_sum is not adding the values that i am getting from data variable.

```js
exports.GetMonthsFWSeasonFullSeasonValues = () => {
  var promises = [];
  var array_sum = 0;
  for(var month_index = 9; month_index <= 27 ; month_index++){
    const elm_xpath = utils.GetXpathForSubCategory(chosen_season_index, month_index);
    promises.push(element(by.xpath(elm_xpath)).getText());
  }
  return Promise.all(promises).then(function(data){
    if(data != null) {
      for (var array_index = 0; array_index < data.length; array_index++){
        array_sum += data[array_index];
        console.log('sum of values from months',array_sum);
      }
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to add two strings. The + operator is overloaded in JS, so with numbers it adds them, but with strings it concatenates them. You need to convert them to ints or floats by using parseInt or parseFloat, and get rid of the commas and $ signs out of it, something like:

```
var num = '$1,100'
parseInt(num.replace(/[$,]/g, ''))
```

Which would give 1100 if you printed it. After they are in number format, you can sum them.

Or if you have the choice to store the numbers in your array as numbers, without the string formatting to start off with, go with that. So much easier.

Comment: i have tried this  :  
var parsed_data = parseInt(data.replace('$', '').replace(',', ''));

It's is giving me an error :   TypeError: data.replace is not a function

Comment: data is an array right? .replace is a method of Strings, so you will need to apply .replace to each element in the array for it to work.